# Como ativar no meu Painel a Header/Cabeçalho - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Preciso ativar meu cabeçalho para que eu possa customizar a minha header através dos recursos que o próprio painel do wordpress oferece.

Nesta imagem está destacada a opção que desejo ativar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O fato de não estar aparecendo é porque estou criando meu tema do zero. Tenho noção que preciso ativar ele na página functions.php.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Para ativar o header do seu theme, use:

`<?php get_header( $name ); ?>`.

Para usar o editor de imagem de header, no `functions.php`, use algo como:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
```

Você pode conferir o uso correto e completo da tag no [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Custom_Header).

E consulte [aqui](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) para maiores detalhes.